# Cancelling upload with WebClient?

Tags: vb.net, ftp, webclient

Using the following VB.Net simple code to upload files in FTP, a call to WebClient.CancelAsync() doesn't actually cancel the upload.

Does someone know why, and what can be done about this?

```
Private Sub UploadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.UploadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    'TO-DO: Why is pbar empty?
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

    Label1.Text = e.BytesSent & " bytes sent"
End Sub

Private Sub UploadFileCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.UploadFileCompletedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Done!")
    Button1.Text = "Upload"
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim client As New WebClient

    If Button1.Text = "Cancel" Then
        'TO-DO: Doesn't actually cancel upload!
        client.CancelAsync()

        Button1.Text = "Upload"
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    Else
        Button1.Text = "Cancel"

        Const MYFILE = "big.file.bin"
        Const LocalFile As String = "C:\" & MYFILE

        Dim RemoteFile As String = "ftp://upload.acme.com/" & MYFILE

        client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("anonymous", "test")
        client.Proxy = Nothing

        AddHandler client.UploadFileCompleted, AddressOf UploadFileCompleted
        AddHandler client.UploadProgressChanged, AddressOf UploadProgressChanged

        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100

        Try
            client.UploadFileAsync(New Uri(RemoteFile), LocalFile)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

        client.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use VB myself but it looks to me like you are calling client.cancelAsync() on the wrong client.

You are making a new client each time you press the cancel/upload button.

If you want to cancel the first client you started you need to instantiate it externally to the click_handler.

Also why are you using the button label to check if the client should be cancelled?

You can do if client.IsBusy ...

Comment: I don't know, I just googled for samples and found the above. Thank for the infos, I'll investigate.